# Use Facebook Graph API to Show Page's Posts in TableView

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

I want to have a simple `UITableView` in my app that each cell will show a post from a public Facebook Page.  Is this something that can be accomplished with Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

According Facebook documentation you can use graph api to achieve this.

> /{page-id}/feed
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by
>   this page, or by others on this page. There are other edges which
>   provide more specific sets of posts:
>
> - /{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this    page.
> - /{page-id}/tagged shows the posts that this page was tagged in    and the 'posts to page'
> - /{page-id}/promotable_posts shows only the    posts that can be boosted (includes unpublished and scheduled posts).
>
> All of these derivative edges share the exact same reading structure, 
>   however /feed should be used for all publishing purposes. They all
>   have an upper boundary for the limit parameter of 250 posts.
>   Specifying any higher limit will throw an error.

Calling example:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/feed"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed?locale=es_LA

Hoe it helps!

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions for what to do with the returned data to get it into a tableview?